# Creating a simple scripted 'language' - VARIANT-like value type

Tags: c++, variant

For a rules engine developed in C++, one of the core features is the value type. What I have so far is a bit like a COM-style VARIANT - each value knows its type. There are some rules for type conversion but it's a bit messy.

I wondered if there are nice drop-in value classes I could use which solve this, without requiring me to use a whole pre-built system. For instance maybe boost has something?

Comment: You should limit implicit conversions initially: it's easier to add them later than to remove once they're widely used.

Comment: That's probably good advice, my initial attempt has some weird inconsistencies on conversions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking for [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html) or [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/variant.html)?

There are basically three types of variant implementations:

1. A type that can be freely casted between types (think untyped languages) -- `boost::lexical_cast` is your friend here, or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/variant.html)...
2. A type that can hold any type, but is typesafe -- e.g. initialized with an `int`, stays an `int` and doesn't allow to be treated implicitly like anything else -- this is the [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html) type
3. The evil *allow anything* type -- cast to what you want without error checking, no type information held -- think `void*`

Comment: Sounds more like he wants boost::variant. http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: I need to look more closely but boost::variant sounds like the answer, to save me writing all that stuff from scratch.